# In what circumstances is uri passed to Android's ContentObserver.onChange() callback?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

The onChange() method of Android's ContentObserver class says, "Includes the changed content Uri when available." In what circumstances is the URI available? In what circumstances is it not available?

The uri parameter was added in API level 16 (Android 4.1) and so I would expect it to be set in Android 4.1 and newer. However I'm seeing a case on Android 4.3 where uri is not set.

#### Method 1: Works

MyContentObserver.onChange() is called and is passed a valid uri:

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(myUri, true, new MyContentObserver());
```

#### Method 2: Doesn't work--why not?

MyContentObserver.onChange() is called but the uri parameter is null:

```
contentResolver.query();
cursor.registerContentObserver(new MyContentObserver);
```

Is this expected? Is one of these preferred over the other? I've tested this using "content://com.google.android.gm/me@example.com/labels" and using my own custom ContentProvider.

Comment: I just stumbled on the same thing, probably a bug. I went with your method 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question, but still unanswered. So I will add my answer in case people is still curious about it.

When your content provider notifies the registered observer using `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(URI, "your_uri");`, it asks the `ContentResponder` for it. The return value from that method is the `ContentObserver` that you registered with the `registerContentObserver()` method of the content responder, which is what you did in the first case. However, in the second case, you registered the observer in the `Cursor` using the `registerContentObserver()` method of the `Cursor`, so the `ContentResponder` doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting `ContentObserver` upon common tables(e.g people, mediaprovider etc) then unfortunately you might not receive any `Uri` as an argument, it might be blank as it depends upon underneath content provider implementation. To receive an valid `Uri` upon change, respective `ContentProvider` has to be modified to notify change along with `URI`.

e.g `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri, "your_uri");` // this notifies all the  registered `ContentObserver` with `Uri` of modified concerned dataset.

If you are writing your own `ContentProvider` then use above mentioned line whenever you perform update, delete or insert operation on your database.

Comment: Any idea why cursor.registerContentObserver() always gives a null uri (even when the ContentPRovider calls notifyChange() with a uri)? Is that expected?

Comment: @MarkDoliner in the docs for ContentObserver, it points out that the version of onChange() with a URI parameter is only in API 16 (Android 4.1) and up. Maybe that's your issue.

Comment: I think that was probably not the cause of the specific problem I was seeing because I was testing using 4.3.